# Istio End User Authentication with JWT on a GRPC service

Tags: kubernetes, jwt, grpc, istio, envoyproxy

I would like to set up an [auth policy](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/authn-policy/#end-user-authentication) on a GRPC service through Istio.

Currently, it's possible to add the policy on regular HTTP services, as you can use the `Authorization` header to pass the JWT token to the service. I'm a bit lost as it doesn't seem to be a similar policy for GRPC services (where you could include the token in the [metadata](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/Documentation/grpc-metadata.md) of the request).

Has anyone managed to add an auth policy to a GRPC service managed by Istio?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve `Authorization` Header parsed to `md['authorization']` for you if you use [JSON-to-GRPC Gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/) as a middleware between [istio ingress](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress) and [grpc service](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/concepts.html#service-definition).

`JSON-to-GRPC Gateway` [source-code line](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/blob/v1.1.0/runtime/context.go#L51) where `HTTP Header` `Authorization` is parsed and appended to *pairs* that will become metadatas:

```
for key, vals := range req.Header {
    for _, val := range vals {
        if key == "Authorization" {
            pairs = append(pairs, "authorization", val)
            continue
        }
```

PS.: If there's a way use a custom middleware function in *istio* itself, you could replicate the `grpc-gateway` logic to achieve the same behaviour.

that can later be accessed in the *grpc-service* via `context` like this:

```
// retrieve metadata from context
md, ok := metadata.FromContext(ctx)

md["authorization"]
```

Comment: The question is looking for a solution where a grpc client sends an authorization header to the grpc server and how to use Istio to intercept and validate the jwt token.